# How to: Use async methods with LINQ custom extension method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, extension-methods

I have a LINQ custom extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TKey> property)
{
    return items.GroupBy(property).Select(x => x.First());
}
```

And I am using it like this:

```
var spc = context.pcs.DistinctBy(w => w.province).Select(w => new
            {
                abc = w
            }).ToList();
```

But the problem is I don't want ToList() I want something like this

```
var spc = await context.pcs.DistinctBy(w => w.province).Select(w => new
             {
                 abc = w
             }).ToListAsync();
```

With Async. But async is not found. How can I make my custom method distinctBy as such so I can also use it asynchronously?

Comment: Have you to have tried use a `IQueryable` instead of a `IEnumerable` for both return type and argument items?

Looks like `ToListAsync` is a extension method on `IQueryable` for EF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `ToListAsync()` extension method is extending an `IQueryable<T>`, but your `DistinctBy()` method is extending (and returning) an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Obviously, `ToListAsync()` isn't available for `IEnumerable<T>` because it uses Linq-To-Objects (in-memory) and cannot potentially block (no I/O is involved).

Try this instead:

```
public static IQueryable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> items, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> property)
{
    return items.GroupBy(property).Select(x => x.First());
}
```

Notice that I also changed the `property` parameter from `Func<>` to `Expression<Func<>>` in order to match `Queryable.GroupBy` (and avoid `Enumerable.GroupBy`).

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: As an addition to clarify, it is best practise to use a `IQueryable` as far as possible instead of `IEnumerable` to avoid making multiple database queries. :)

Comment: @Hypnobrew, That's not always true. Usually you'll want to explicitly fetch all the data you know you need beforehand, then return it as `IEnumerable<T>`. Always returning `IQueryable<T>` is error-prone and sometimes considered a leaky abstraction.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If you let your `IQueryable` flow between classes, and even worse, between layers, there could potentially be a leaky abstraction. In the example above it looks like an isolated place where an IQuerable is suitable, where you want to postpone the query a far as possible.